# Problema seleccionar string mas larga php

Tags: php, array, string

Tengo una array donde tengo que obtener el número de letras del string mas largo pero me da error.

Error :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: max(): Argument 
#1 ($value) must be of type array, int given in /var/www/html/PHP/Arrays/temp.php:12
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/PHP/Arrays/temp.php(12): max()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/PHP/Arrays/temp.php on line 12`
```

Mi código :

```php
$cosas = ["manzana, pelota, marciano, pan, sopa"];
$longitud = 0;
// Max string length
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($cosas); $i++) {
    $longitud = max(strlen($cosas[$i]));
}
```

Comment: Hola, te sugerimos revisar:  https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1725/c%c3%b3mo-deben-gestionarse-las-cuentas-t%c3%adtere-en-stack-exchange y https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3195/por-qu%c3%a9-me-quitaron-400-puntos-de-reputaci%c3%b3n/3196#3196
evita realizar cuentas para obtener votación positiva ya que es una práctica prohibida en el sitio, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que estas utilizando la función `max()` para obtener la longitud del string y no has de utilizar esa funcion.

Debes de recorrer tu array con un bucle e ir comprobando si la longitud del string donde donde te encuentras en el array es mas grande que `$len`.

Para esto, utiliza condicionales `if` y la función `strlen()` para obtener el la longitud del string.

Tu código debería verse de la siguiente forma :

```
    $cosas = ["manzana, pelota, marciano, pan, sopa"];
    $len = 0;

    // Obtienes el string mas largo 
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++) {
        if ($len < strlen($array[$i])) {
            $len = strlen($array[$i]);
        }
    }
```

Lo que hacemos aquí es comprobar cada indice del array hasta que finalize `[0,1,2,3...]`.

Aquí, miramos si el valor `$len`es mas pequeño que la longitud del string donde nos encontramos en el array. Si es así asignamos el valor de este a `$len`.

**Por ejemplo :**
Si `$len < $array[0]` (manzana), Asignamos `$len` a la longitud del string del indice del array donde nos encontramos.

Si no es así, mantenemos el valor de `$len`.    Esto lo realizamos con cada indice del array.

Comment: En caso de que necesites alguna aclaración o tengas alguna duda escribe un comentario !

Comment: Funciona muchas gracias

Comment: Hola, te sugerimos revisar:  https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1725/c%c3%b3mo-deben-gestionarse-las-cuentas-t%c3%adtere-en-stack-exchange y https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3195/por-qu%c3%a9-me-quitaron-400-puntos-de-reputaci%c3%b3n/3196#3196
evita realizar cuentas para obtener votación positiva ya que es una práctica prohibida en el sitio, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Comenzando que tienes el array mal estructurado, ya que cada palabra no está dentro de sus propias comillas dobles **(")** o simples **(')**, pues todo lo que tienes en tu array termina siendo un string, por lo tanto lo que hagas te dirá que tu string más largo es lo que tienes añadido en tu array.

Con [max](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.max) lo puedes hacer, pero haciendo uso de la siguiente manera:

```
// Array de palabras a buscar
$cosas = ["manzana", "pelota", "marciano", "pan", "sopa"];

//encontramos solo la cantidad de letras en la palabra más larga
$len = max(array_map('strlen', $cosas));

// Combinamos el array de cosas con el valor que obtenemos de su recorrido
$mapping = array_combine($cosas, array_map('strlen', $cosas));

//buscamos la key y valor del proceso anterior
$string = array_keys($mapping, max($mapping));

// Obtenemos 
// int(8)
// array(1) {
//  [0]=>
//  string(8) "marciano"
// }    

var_dump($len, $string);
```

Te dejo el [snippet](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/32686712607bf1ca608ae86366b21107b99271b2), por si quieres probarlo